# How do I display a message on login for Windows 8/8.1?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, security, group-policy

I've configured the following settings in my local security policy:

- Interactive logon: Message text for users attempting to log on
- Interactive logon: Message title for users attempting to log on

However, the system still does not display the login text.

I've also tried forcing the use of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, with the above settings also configured, and that didn't work either.

Is there another setting, or a different area where this should be configured, that I'm missing for Windows 8?

All affected systems are using Windows 8.1 Pro, and are not currently joined to a domain.

Modifying the Lock Screen image is not an acceptable option – solutions must effectively emulate (or, preferably, enable) the normally expected effects of the policies listed above.

Comment: Note: Everywhere I've come across an online article on how to do this, they're just referencing the two "Interactive logon" settings I've already applied.

Comment: Post your gpresult as HTML on pastebin.

Comment: Funny question : Do you have an account password?

Comment: Not sure why it's funny, but yes - the accounts do have passwords.

Comment: Was Windows 8 a clean install, or an update to Windows 7?

Comment: @harrymc One is a Surface Pro 3. The other is a laptop that came with 8.1. Strangely, on a re-test, the Surface Pro 3 appears to work with just the policy changes. It'll be awhile before I can check the other, though.

Comment: Is it possible that you didn't then reboot after these policy changes? They need reboot to be effective.

Comment: Rebooted twice when testing the Surface last time.

Comment: If you have a Screen saver, try to disable it.

Comment: In the vein of rebooting, `gpupdate /force` has been known to clear up policy related issues before.

Comment: @BowlesCR Is that still relevant/functional when the system's not a domain member?

Comment: Yes, (or at least I believe so)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solution :

Edit registry to :

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]
"LegalNoticeText"="Warning this is my message"
"LegalNoticeCaption"="My caption"
"DisableCAD"=dword:00000001
```

DisableCAD may not be needed

## Infos & Debug :

- *Check your different value under :*

  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
- *GPO populates the registry under different keys :*

  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\
  legalnoticecaption
  legalnoticetext
- *GPEDIT.MSC Settings :*

  Navigate through Local Computer Policy \Computer Configuration \Windows Settings \Local Policies\Security Options
  On the right pane window find INTERACTIVE LOGIN: Message text for users attempting to log on type your warning away in that box.
- *Reboot related issue 1 :*

  gpupdate has been known to clear up policy related issues

  `gpupdate /force`
- *Reboot related issue 2 :*

  Force reboot the system
  `"shutdown /s /t 0"` then turn on

## Links :

[Deeper info about LegalNoticeText](http://appsensebigot.blogspot.be/2013/04/setting-legalnoticecaption-and.html)

[Carriage Return](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/238149)

[Similar issue on TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/3ee8c74e-7146-439d-838f-89b77e30169f/windows-7-legalnoticetext)

[Detailed process](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/displaying-customized-start-message-windows-8)

## Captures :

[image: Capture 1]

[image: Capture 2]

[image: Capture 3]

[image: Capture 4]

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked after setting the "Interactive logon: Do not require CTRL+ALT+DEL" group policy to **Disabled**.

Answer (score 0):

Found possible solution from link:

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to display `Run` command.
2. On the `Run` command Type `Regedit`.
3. Browse to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->SOFTWARE->Microsoft->WindowsNT->CurrentVersion->Winlogon`
4. From there Set Value of `Legal NoticeText` and `LegalNoticeCaption` to **1**.
5. Close The window.
6. Next, go to `Run` command, By pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> Key.
7. Type `Gpedit.msc`
8. Navigate through `Local Computer Policy->ComputerConfiguration->Windows Settings->Local Policies->Security Options`
9. In the right pane window find INTERACTIVE LOGIN: Message text for users attempting to log on type your warning away in that box.**
10. Click on it Type your Msg,Save and Exit, Then Reboot Your PC, You Will find Your message Before Login Screen.

[Source.](http://hopeitisuseful.blogspot.com/2015/06/how-to-display-custom-message-on.html)

Comment: How is this answer different from intika's answer?  I blame the editor for making the link less noticeable, the reason this answer seems like it was copied from a website, is because it was.  Sadly it appears the sole purpose of this answer is to advertise that website.

Answer (score 0):

Using `gpupdate` or `gpupdate /force` commands in Command Prompt and restarting the machine will apply the group policy successfully. In some cases, this is what will be needed in order to make the policy update.